# I faced an empty training_Data

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

So I tried [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j-3vuBynnOE&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDfhTox0AjmQ6tvTgMBZBEXN&index=2) (minutes 11:58) trying to implement on my CNN which consist of 10 species on the dataset.

i got no error to load data

```
DATADIR = "dataset"
CATEGORIES = ["Dendrobium_crumenatum","Grammatophyllum_speciosum", "Coelogyne_swaniana", 
              "Bulbophyllum_purpurascens", "Agrostophyllum_stipulatum", 
              "Spathoglottis_plicata", "Phalaenopsis_amabilis", "Nabaluia_angustifolia", 
              "Habenaria_rhodocheila_hance"]

 here the example of the output
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
```

then the next section is

```
training_data = []
def create_training_data():
    for category in CATEGORIES:
        path = os.path.join(DATADIR,category)
        class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category)
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            try:
                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img),cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE))
                training_data.append([new,array, class_num])
            except Exception as e:
                pass
create_training_data()
```

but when I print `prin(len(training_data))`

i got this as output

> 0

and when i tried

```
import random
random.shuffle(training_data)
for sample in training_data[:10]:
    print (sample[1])
```

it shows no output. is that means, my training data is empty?
or because of the index of categories being used? because I'm using 10 class while in tutorial used 2 class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make your training_data global

```
training_data =[]
def create_training_data():
    global training_data
    for category in CATEGORIES:
        path = os.path.join(DATADIR,category)
        class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category)
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            try:
                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img),cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                new_array = cv2.resize(img_array,(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
                training_data.append([new_array,class_num])
            except Exception as e:
                pass
create_training_data()
```

Comment: yes thank you i solved it, but can i know what's the reason?